# hbase + gwt multi module app, issues with slf4j and resources

Tags: java, gwt, log4j, hbase

I've found a lot of articles/questions dealing with this problem, but there was no answer that worked for me yet.

I'm using GWT 2.5 with the eclipse plugin. eclipse version is Juno with Java7.

Everytime I start the app it first tells me that log4j was not configured properly (no appenders...) and also my HBaseAdmin can't connect to HBase (which is running).

All of the answers tell me that I have to put the resources into WEB-INF/classes directory. In order to do that automatically I added the files into the root src directory. But still nothing.

Maybe it's worth mentioning that I don't use maven (b/c all the other projects are no maven projects either, and there is no time to introduce maven at the moment)

Thank you for any hints what might be missing.

**EDIT:**

somehow I don't get any warning anymore, but I didn't do anything except restarting over and over. Thus this should be working now. But, Zookeeper now throws

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

I divided the gwt app up to the UI part, the executing implementation of the service is a seperate project, also the model is seperate. I first just added the required libraries to the projects that really need them. Know I also added them to the main GWT app, but that didn't help either. Any ideas?

Comment: Did manually copying the files into WEB-INF/classes help?

Comment: I don't know what helped, as I didn't do anything but restarting eclipse in order to read the resources. thus this isn't an issue anymore, the classes folder is correct, I just need to be patient with eclipse i guess...But then zookeeper can't load slf4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoggerFactory classes you are using is from slfj-api-1.6.1.jar . Try adding that jar into your WEB-INF/lib and classpath. Also we usually use it conjunction with slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar .

Note: We are using version 1.6.1 as indicated by GWT sample examples available with gwt downloads.

Comment: that did the trick. I already tried this as well, but with a different version (the one coming with hbase). Thank you!